# Table is not created after running the query

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a problem to create a table. What is happening is the following, I have an xml file which is what I want the queries that are executed when I change the version of the database. The problem is that it reaches a height of processing the query is executed but the change in the database is not taken, the strange thing is that in my xml file has two different queries, the first runs but not the second and the worst is that it is not pointed any bank error, my script is correct and is returning all queries but it happens and I do not know why. Below is my function responsible for executing the queries of my xml:

```
private boolean execSqlByQuery(List<String[]> listaQuery, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Boolean result = false;
    if(!listaQuery.isEmpty()){
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < listaQuery.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < listaQuery.get(i).length; j++){
                    db.beginTransaction();
                    Log.d("SQL", listaQuery.get(i)[j].toString());
                    db.execSQL(listaQuery.get(i)[j].toString());
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
            }
            result = true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            result = false;
        }finally{
            listaQuery.clear();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) Log your exceptions 2) Move the `endTransaction()` to a finally block. (Every call to `beginTransaction()` must be matched with a corresponding `endTransaction()`, also in the case of an exception occurring.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like:

```
private boolean execSqlByQuery(List<String[]> listaQuery, SQLiteDatabase db) {
Boolean result = false;
if(!listaQuery.isEmpty()){
db.beginTransaction();
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < listaQuery.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < listaQuery.get(i).length; j++){

                Log.d("SQL", listaQuery.get(i)[j].toString());
                db.execSQL(listaQuery.get(i)[j].toString());


            }
        }
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        result = true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        result = false;
    }finally{
if (db!= null) {
 db.endTransaction();
}
        listaQuery.clear();
    }
}
return result;
}
```